# How to declare a variable to be used by the imported module

Tags: python

I have a module with the name `my_module.py`
Inside of this module there is a function `my_function`:

```
def myFunction():
    print my_variable
```

Apparently when this functions is called it prints `my_variable` which is not instantiated anywhere yet. So, calling `myFunction()` from inside of the module itself will crash the execution.

Now, aside from `my_module.py` I have another script with the name `my_app.py` residing in the same folder.

Inside of `my_app.py` I am importing `my_module.py` and instantiating `my_variable` under its namespace. After `my_variable` is instantiated I am calling `my_module.myFunction()` which picks up `my_variable` and prints its context out:

```
import module
module.my_variable = 'this variable is instantiated inside of another script'
module.myFunction()
```

While this approach works I wonder if it is designed properly. Is there other way to instantiate a variable outside the `imported module` to be used by this `imported module`?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: Python doesn't have variable declarations. But anyway, it sounds like you should be passing an argument to the function instead of relying on global state....

Comment: Sure. It references them by names instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that in this context. But regardless, it is incorrect to say that you have "declared" a variable in Python.

Comment: But anyway, the answer is no, Python doesn't have truly global scope - many would consider that a good thing - instead, "global" scope really means module-level scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import module
module.my_variable = 'this variable is instantiated inside of another script'
module.myFunction()
```

> While this approach works I wonder if it is designed properly.

No, this is not designed properly. One proper way is to pass the value to the function explicitly.

> Is there other way to instantiate a variable outside the imported module to be used by this imported module?

Just have another module were you declare this variable(s). For example `my_vars.py`:

```
 my_variable = 'this variable is instantiated inside of another script'
```

Then in `my_module.py`:

```
import my_vars

def myFunction():
    print my_vars.my_variable
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but it's generally best practice to not mutate "global" variables. Every time you'd want to use `my_function()` in your code you'd have to explicitly change `my_variable` first, which can trigger side effects in your code if other functions/methods are depending on it. The best way would be to rewrite `my_function()` so that it accepts `my_variable` as an argument

Comment: I am using `my_function()` as an example. So things are kept relatively simple to explain. There are times when we need a global scope variable. So every module that gets imported is able to get an access to the same object or a variable.

Comment: Database connecton object could be shared as a "really" global variable for example. Let's say there are several modules in your program that require DB connection object. Sure, we could instantiate DB connection object in every module. Or we could write the modules functions in a such way that they get the connection object as an argument. But it is a lot of work by my opinion. It would be so much simpler if we would just instantiate a single DB connection object and make it available to all the modules imported.

Comment: I read your question too fast. I guess you are not mutating anything and only trying to instantiate `my_variable` outside of `my_module`, correct? Well there is no clean way for `my_function` to know of any variables outside its containing scope, which is `my_module`. When you do `import my_module`, you're binding the names in `my_module` to `my_app`. This means you can access all names in `my_module` from `my_app`, not the other way around. However, there is a hack around it using `__builtin__`, which is very dangerous. So passing `my_variable` as an argument is still the best method.

Comment: Regarding your DB example, yes it'd make sense to have a global DB connection object. But if don't write your functions to accept the DB object as a parameter, you'd have to make the DB object available to all imported scopes using `__builtin__`  which is again a very dangerous way to do it.